# insert failed: Method in meteor 1.3 and react

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I want insert simple text to the mongo database with react but, when i submit the form print this line in console:

`insert failed: Method '/resolutions/insert' not found`

Tips: `autopublish` and `insecure` already installed. and i have react 15 and meteor 1.3.1

Here is my code:

```html
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

Resolutions = new Mongo.Collection('resolutions');
Resolutions.allow({
  insert: function(userId,doc) {
    return true;
  }
});

// import './index.html';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  AddResolution(event) {
    let text = this.refs.resolutions.value.trim();
    // Insert into database
    Resolutions.insert({
      text: text,
      complete: false,
      createAt: new Date()
    });
    this.refs.resolutions.value = "";
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My swsolutions</h1>
        <form className="new-resolution" onSubmit={this.AddResolution.bind(this)}>
          <input type="text" ref="resolutions" placeholder="Finish React Meteor"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The collection also needs to be defined on the server.

Comment: Also, `collection.allow` is a server-side function.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Thanks, it's work now.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem an hour ago. You're going to want to do 'Resolutions._collection.insert' instead of just 'Resolutions.insert'.